# Full screen images in loop with chocolat js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chocolat.js

I'm trying to create a full screen slideshow with images in a loop with [chocolat js](http://chocolat.insipi.de/).

The getting started documentation says to start with:

```
<div class="chocolat-parent" data-chocolat-title="set title">
    <a class="chocolat-image" href="series/1.jpg" title="caption image 1">
        <img class="chocolat-open" width="100" src="series/1.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a class="chocolat-image" href="series/2.jpg" title="caption image 2">
        <img width="100" src="series/2.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a class="chocolat-image" href="series/3.jpg" title="caption image 3">
        <img width="100" src="series/3.jpg"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

My javascript is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chocolat-parent').Chocolat({
        loop: true,
        imageSize: 'cover',
    });
});
```

But how can I make it automatically open and loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the code below for the demo.

for more details, you can check the [documentation](https://github.com/nicolas-t/Chocolat/blob/master/readme.md)

This is what you need

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var instance = $('.chocolat-parent').Chocolat({
    loop: true,
    fullScreen : true,
    imageSize: 'cover',
    }).data('chocolat');
    instance.api().open();
    window.setInterval(function(){
        instance.api().next();
    },2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chocolat/0.4.19/css/chocolat.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chocolat/0.4.19/js/jquery.chocolat.min.js"></script>

<div class="chocolat-parent" data-chocolat-title="set title">
    <a class="chocolat-image" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5xFh.jpg" title="caption image 1">
        <img class="chocolat-open" width="100" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5xFh.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a class="chocolat-image" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbOvd.jpg" title="caption image 2">
        <img width="100" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbOvd.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a class="chocolat-image" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjOFl.jpg" title="caption image 3">
        <img width="100" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjOFl.jpg"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't autoplay. And it's like there's a delay on opening full screen at start.

Comment: There's still a delay at opening webpage.

Comment: delay is by default because first it will loads all the images and then open that images in fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
      <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

    var instance = $('#example1').Chocolat({
    loop: true,
      imageSize: 'cover',
    }).data('chocolat');
  instance.api().open();
            setInterval(function(){  instance.api().next();}, 3000);

});
    </script>
```

Comment: This doesn't autoplay and open.

Comment: `setTimeout` will call only once